# How to get the real file path in product environment

Tags: c#, wpf, io

I'm writing a PowerShell ISE add-on with WPF, there's a exe file in my project, I set it as Copy always. I need to execute it when the add-on is loaded. I use this method to execute it:

```
string exePath = Path.GetFullPath("test.exe");
Process.Start(exePath);
```

in the debug mode, it works, but if I execute PowerShell ISE directly, system couldn't find the file with the path, anyone can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without complete understanding how is your project structured and the ways you are trying to run it, I'd suggest that the reason might be that "test.exe" is not in the current folder of the running app.

In such cases I do as follows:

1) in case I know full path the file, I specify it:

```
string exePath = Path.GetFullPath("C:\test.exe");
Process.Start(exePath);
```

2) In case I know that file is in the same folder as the calling assembly dll, I do it like this (example in vb.net):

```
Public Shared Function GetMyPath() As String
    ' SomeYourType is any class from your assembly, you can f.e. create a private class with single purpose of being used by this function
    Dim installPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType(SomeYourType)).CodeBase)
    Return installPath.Substring(6)
End Function
```

And then I use it like this:

```
string exePath = Path.Combine(GetMyPath(), "test.exe");
Process.Start(exePath);
```